# Can you reference a .NET Core class library from a regular c# Class Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, class-library

I have two class libraries. One is a **C# Class Library** *(from Visual Studio 2015 -> New Project -> Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Class Library)*. The other is **C# Class Library (.NET Core)** *(from Visual Studio 2015 -> New Project -> Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Class Library (.NET Core))*.

I added a reference from my C# Class Library to my .NET Core Class Library, but it's not finding the namepsace when I try to do `using CoreClassLibraryNamespace;`

Is it possible to reference a .NET Core library from a regular C# Class Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a pure .NET Core library from a classic .NET project as of today. You can, however, create a Portable Class Library (template "Class Library (Portable)", aka PCL) with targets ".NET Framework 4.x" and "ASP.NET Core 1.0". The resulting library can be referenced from Core and classic projects.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 enables that. You can try its RC build.